# Fitting a table properly in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this simple table. How do I prevent the table  from overflowing the boundaries of the panel ? What is the right way to handle this in bootstrap when the contained table has cell data that is too long? I looked at panel with table example here to write what I have:

[Bootstrap panel with table](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables)

I believe I am using the outer most "container" div incorrectly as well as I am applying row classes to it directly.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  background-color: #3F88BF;
}

.table-condensed {
  font-size: 12px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"> <!-- div container -->
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1 id="top">Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1 id="abc">ABC</h1>
                <a class="pull-right" href="#top">top</a>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Head1</th>
                        <th>Head2</th>
                        <th>Head3</th>
                        <th>Head4</th>
                        <th>Head5</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data1</td>
                        <td>Data2</td>
                        <td>Data3</td>
                        <td>Data4</td> <td>Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data555555</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your cell data is too long it should be solved using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. It will render Render an ellipsis ("...") to represent clipped text.
So your table cell will not overflow.
You will also have to use `table-layout: fixed`.

> If you use `table-layout: fixed`- Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

**Modified Snippet**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  background-color: #3F88BF;
}

.table-condensed {
  font-size: 12px;

}
.table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"> <!-- div container -->
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1 id="top">Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1 id="abc">ABC</h1>
                <a class="pull-right" href="#top">top</a>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Head1</th>
                        <th>Head2</th>
                        <th>Head3</th>
                        <th>Head4</th>
                        <th colspan="4">Head5</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data1</td>
                        <td>Data2</td>
                        <td>Data3</td>
                        <td >Data4</td> <td colspan="4">Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data555555</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry this did not quite work.  `table-layout:fixed;` caused my headers for nested tables to get squished up. And `text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;` did not have any effect without it.

Comment: Try using col-span on the squised up header..that might help. I edited my answer snippet check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `table-layout: fixed;` and in the last column use `word-wrap: break-word;`, because the last column contains a single word that is too long.

```css
body { font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; background-color: #3F88BF; }
.table-condensed { font-size: 12px; table-layout: fixed;}
.table-condensed td {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"> <!-- div container -->
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1 id="top">Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1 id="abc">ABC</h1>
                <a class="pull-right" href="#top">top</a>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Head1</th>
                        <th>Head2</th>
                        <th>Head3</th>
                        <th>Head4</th>
                        <th>Head5</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data1</td>
                        <td>Data2</td>
                        <td>Data3</td>
                        <td>Data4</td> <td>Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data5555555555555Data555555</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```